# how to make this footer stay at bottom of page even window is small

Tags: html, css

I am pretty much stuck in this html problem.

I have a page. i want its footer to stay at the bottom and have certian distance to element above it. here the Twitter + G+ div.

please see the css inside `@media (min-width:481)`.

i tried this:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
.fuss{
 position: absolute; 
 bottom: 0;
}
```

this works for big screens, but if i resize the window to small 15' screen laptop, footer is going over my Twitter and G+ elements. why is this?

this is the page: http://www.bibago.de/test.html  footer works fine in big screens, but in small screens the footer goes over other elements and doesnot stay at bottom.

please help.

thanks.

Comment: I don't see your footer on top of the buttons in any resolution. Did you change it already?

Comment: @putvande, in small screens, you see it okay. but if you watch it in big screens, footer has a distance to bottom of page and not sticking to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special for the footer to appear at the bottom. Simply put it at the end of your page, and as HTML is rendered line by line, it will appear as the last thing (always at the bottom).

```
.fuss{
    margin-top: 50px;   
}
```

Comment: i mean, it should stick to bottom. will it do?

Comment: Why are you not trying it?

Comment: @Doniyor i tried it on your page using Firebug and it should do the job. Try it

Comment: mavili the Great! :). working like anything :D thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this:

```
.fuss {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: this will fix the div in screen, i dont want it

Comment: Yes it fixes at the bottom of the page. Wasn't it what you wanted?